# Mars sized planet with 83% Earth gravity?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, science-fiction, gravity

For one of my stories I’ve developed a planet with approximately the same total surface area as Mars. This planet has high quantities of heavier metals/elements (especially silver) and it has roughly 83% earth gravity. It’s very earth like in terms of environment (a little cooler but the temps and atmosphere are well within human limitations. Is this planet feasible?

Comment: It would be much easier to dunk.

Comment: Well, Mars, as it is, has about 38% of Earth's gravity so, without having done the math, my guess is that you'd need to slightly more than double the density in order to get the gravity you want.  Mars has about 71% of the density of Earth, so even changing to the same composition isn't enough.

Comment: (continued)  So, you'd need to replace most of the planet's iron core with something exceptionally dense like platinum or gold to make it happen.   So, it's feasible in the sense that the physics works but such a planet is not likely to come into being naturally or to be practically constructible short of outright magic.

Comment: The gravity is achievable, yes by adding a lot of more dense elements. This would have the side effect of making the surface utterly toxic to all life. And I don't mean just Cyanide-on-anthrax biscuits level toxic, I'm talking arsenic floating on Mercury with Cadmium sprinkles on top toxic.

Comment: Re: heavy metal toxicity, in terms of density, gold and platinum are near the top and both are nearly chemically inert, see https://www.thoughtco.com/elements-listed-by-density-606528

Comment: Many metals have high density: mean density of earth 5.5Kg/L, copper: 9Kg/L, Lead: 11, Gold/Tunsten: ~19, Osmium 23.  So it is credible to have a 11Kg/L planet if it contains a big core of those elements. However, looking at astronomical databases, it seems rather exotic to have more than 5Kg/L

Comment: to achieve the needed 8.5t/m3, even making the planet 100% iron core would not suffice. There is insufficient gravity to compress the core to this extent. So the core HAD to be made of something denser than iron. And to have a reasonably useful crust, it also needs a hefty helping of silicon, oxygen, etc. This means not even nickel suffices, you need to make the core of wierd stuff, in abundances 10e3 to 10e10 times more common than their abundance on Earth. Tricky

Comment: @PcMan In fact, cyanide and anthrax would be pretty much impossible since they are both organic - cyanide is produced by living organisms, anthrax *is* a living organism.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yes darrel. which is why, if you look carefully, i stated " I don't mean just Cyanide-on-anthrax biscuits level toxic, but..".

Comment: @PcMan Yes, I'm agreeing with you, just clarifying a point that might not be obvious for some.

Comment: While we're on the topic of toxicity, regarding "This planet has high quantities of heavier metals/elements (especially silver)", the querent should investigate silver's own toxicity by looking up "argyria" and "toxicity of silver compounds".

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan for plot reasons I need to have high quantities of native silver in the surface/crust. I have researched argyria; something similar affects the native life in terms of pigmentation. The humans take lots of precautions to prevent it. What if the heavier metals were mostly below the crust and in the core? Could the toxicity and radiation problems be handled with that?

Comment: @SamuelHope  Being outside my realm of expertise I can only make a guess that, at a minimum, the planet would have to be geologically inactive for that to work, i.e. no volcanism / mountain formation anywhere and no tectonic plate motion to circulate heavy metal laden material from below the crust to the surface.  Whether that would be sufficient or not I couldn't say.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan there is no conceivable stellar process that would generate VAST quantities of Silver, without also creating huge quantities of Cesium, Polonium, radium, lead, and a host of the higher heavy metals and radioactive elements. Nucleosynthesis simply is not that selective! Your planet with a silver core will also have many other undesireable heavy elements in it.

Comment: @PcMan  Did you mean that for SamuelHope?  I'm already in agreement with what you said.

Answer (score 9):

So you want have Mars sized planet to have gravity equal to 0.83 the gravity of the Earth.

Some facts and figures:

- The diameter of Mars is 6779 km
- The volume of Mars is 163.116 x 10$^{\sf9}$ km$^\sf3$
- The gravity of Earth is 9.78 m/s$^\sf2$
- 83% of the gravity of Earth is 8.12 m/s$^\sf2$
- The bulk density of Mars is 3.934 t/m$^\sf3$ (or g/cm$^\sf3$)
- The bulk density of Earth is 5.514 t/m$^\sf3$

For your Mars sized planet to have a gravity of 83% that of Earth, 8.12 m/s$^\sf2$, the bulk density of the planet would have to be 8.57 t/m$^\sf3$, which is 1.554 times the bulk density of Earth.

Given that the density of iron is 7.874 t/m$^\sf3$, that level of increase cannot be achieved with a larger iron core.

Nickel has a density of 8.908 t/m$^\sf3$, which would help, but as @L.Dutch suggests, for your Mars sized planet to have a gravity that is 83% that of Earth's would require an anomalously large amount of scarce very heavy metals.

For reference, Earth has the highest bulk density of any planet in the solar a system, followed by Mercury (5.427 t/m$^\sf3$) and Venus (5.243 t/m$^\sf3$).

---

***Edit 1***

I've done a partial simulation, using several rare, valuable and heavy metals to get an idea of what metals and their amounts would be required on your planet to get the criteria you specified.

As can be seen from the table below the amounts more than what they would be [on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_elements_in_Earth%27s_crust) huge by comparison.

As another perspective, nickel has a density of 8.91 t/m$^\sf3$ and your planet needs a density of 8.57 t/m$^\sf3$. You planet could almost be just nickel, with some lighter elements to reduce the overall density.

I very much doubt such a planet is possible

[image]

[image]

---

***Edit 2***

After additional research, prompted by a comment from @J... and a question from the OP in a comment, "*Could such a neutron star collision have occurred near enough to the system (black hole + star binary) that a sufficient amount of heavier metals were caught by the star to create the anomalous planet?*". Planet [K2-38b](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/overview/k2-38%20b#planet_K2-38-b_collapsible) has one of the highest densities of any planet so far discovered, at 11.0 t/m$^\sf3$.

A neutron star collision near a "black hole + star binary" is unlikely to accumulate the material necessary for such a planet.

Instead the [most likely scenario](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020A%26A...641A..92T/abstract) is,

> The best description for the composition of K2-38b comes from an iron-rich Mercury-like model, while K2-38c is better described by a rocky-model with H2 envelope. The maximum collision stripping boundary shows how giant impacts could be the cause for the high density of K2-38b.

Your Mars sized planet with 83% Earth gravity would most likely be the resultant core of a larger planet that was stripped of its outer layers by meteor type bombardment.

It is thought Mercury is a resultant core of a planet that was bombarded. The size of your planet, with a diameter of 6779 km, lies in between the size of Mercury, which has a diameter of 4879 km and K2-38b, which has a diameter of 19,622 km.

[image]

Comment: My understanding (absolutely correct me I’d I’m wrong) is that metals such as iron are produced in supernovas while silver, gold, platinum, and others of the more rare variety are produced when two neutron stars collide. The former being more common than the latter, those metals prevail. Could such a neutron star collision have occurred near enough to the system (black hole + star binary) that a sufficient amount of heavier metals were caught by the star to create the anomalous planet?

Comment: @SamuelHope absolutely. And it would satisfy the density requirements. The only problem is that the planet would consist of a reasonably normal distribution of these heavy metals, rendering the surface composition extremely toxic to any protein-based lifeforms. (also dangerously radioactive)

Comment: `would require an anomalously large amount of scarce very heavy metals.`  Space is vast.  Anomalous for our little backwater solar system is not necessarily anomalous for Space.  [K2-38b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K2-38b), for example, is thought to have a density around 11g/cm3 (=t/m3), which is more than sufficient for this case.

Comment: In fact, [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transiting_exoplanets) has exoplanets of known true mass and there are seven exoplanets in that list with density higher than 8.6g/cm3.

Comment: @J... While I agree with you and I've updated your comments, we have to take those measurements with a pinch of salt. They're all guesstimations that can (and will) vary greatly as our methods and technology of measurement improve (K2-38b was initially believed much more massive and unbelievably denser). Also, all those planets are either gas-giants close to brown dwarfs or, in the case of K2-38b it seems like a Neptune-type planet orbiting so incredibly close to its star that it just vaporized away not just the atmosphere but everything in the crust lighter than iron.

Comment: @Rekesoft Sure, but it exists is the point.  And if it exists and WE, in our stupendously tiny smallness, have seen it, then it is most likely not rare at all in the universe.  Maybe a passing system comes by and kicks K2-38b out of that tight orbit where it settles over billions of years into a goldilocks orbit.  Now OP has a story.

Comment: @SamuelHope: I've added a 2nd edit to answer your question on how your planet could exist - it's the result core of a larger planet that was stripped of its outer layers by meteor type bombardment, over time.

Comment: @Fred So perhaps a small but very dense core remnant like that described experienced an event like when Theia collided with earth, thus getting its crust and becoming the core of a Mars sized but rather dense planet?

Comment: @SamuelHope: A collision between two planets as you describe is possible. Now whether your planet retained some mantle/crustal material after the collision or whether it is just the dense core of one of the planets is something you can speculate. There's nothing to say that an end planet can't be just a naked dense core or a core with a very thin crust after it attracts some of the floating mantle & crustal material from both planets, it depends on the circumstances of the collision.

Comment: @SamuelHope It would be less like the Theia incident as, in that case, there isn't really any reason to think that the Earth or Theia changed their orbit significantly.  Something like K2-38b would need a massive gravitational incident to break from a tight orbit into a larger one - a passing star or star system, for example.  Something on that scale.  After ejection to a larger orbit we can imagine it continuing to accrete crust material, ices/water, etc, in its new orbit - perhaps bombardment from a cometary cloud.

Answer (score 5):

Having high quantities of heavier metals/elements is rather implausible: the heavy elements in the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements) take a long time to be produced

[image: origin of elements]

> Elements heavier than iron are made in energy-absorbing processes in large stars, and their abundance in the universe (and on Earth) generally decreases with increasing atomic number.

In the Milky Way 10 elements, of which the heaviest is iron, account for 99.95% of all the elements, so you see that a very high concentration of heavier elements is unlikely.

[image: table of the relative abundance of elements in Milky Way]

It might still happen that a rocky planet is stripped from the lighter crust and retains a large core made of iron, like it's the case for [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)#Internal_structure):

> Mercury consists of approximately 70% metallic and 30% silicate material. Mercury's density is the second highest in the Solar System at 5.427 $g/cm^3$, only slightly less than Earth's density of 5.515 $g/cm^3$
>
> Therefore, for it to have such a high density, its core must be large and rich in iron.
>
> Mercury's core has a higher iron content than that of any other major planet in the Solar System, and several theories have been proposed to explain this. The most widely accepted theory is that Mercury originally had a metal–silicate ratio similar to common chondrite meteorites, thought to be typical of the Solar System's rocky matter, and a mass approximately 2.25 times its current mass. Early in the Solar System's history, Mercury may have been struck by a planetesimal of approximately 1/6 that mass and several thousand kilometers across. The impact would have stripped away much of the original crust and mantle, leaving the core behind as a relatively major component.

But again, we are still talking about an iron core.

Answer (score 4):

### Turns out, it really is Definitely Realistic

The raw numbers given on the other posts are correct, but they ignore gravity, i.e. pressure. The density of Earth's inner core is around 12 tonnes per cubic meter even though it is mostly composed from iron.

Curiously, the maximum gravitational acceleration – around 11 $m/s^2$ – of Earth is reached at the boundary of the outer core at roughly 3480 kilometers from the center of Earth. This is almost equivalent to the radius of Mars, 3390 km.

The actual composition necessary would necessitate solving an equation state which is beyond me but, for reference, the densest exoplanet is [K2-38b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K2-38b) with a mean density of 11 tonnes per cubic meter.

Figures taken from [Gravity of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) wiki-page.

### UPDATE

[Someone at NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/news/topstory/2007/earthsized_planets.html) has actually done some calculations. Earth mass planet made of iron would have a diameter of roughly 5000 kilometers. This is less than the diameter of Mars (~6800 km). More importantly, the gravity on the surface of the Earth mass iron sphere would be around 7 times higher than on Earth.

This means that 83 % Earth gravity at surface of Mars sized planet sounds plausible and would not even lead to a solid iron sphere.

[image: Earth's gravity according to the Preliminary Reference Earth Model (PREM).[12] Two models for a spherically symmetric Earth are included for comparison. The dark green straight line is for a constant density equal to the Earth's average density. The light green curved line is for a density that decreases linearly from center to surface. The density at the center is the same as in the PREM, but the surface density is chosen so that the mass of the sphere equals the mass of the real Earth. By AllenMc, Wikipedia]

[image: Earth's radial density distribution according to the Preliminary Reference Earth Model (PREM).(by AllenMcC. from Wikipedia)]

Comment: Very interesting! But K2-38b has many times more mass than Earth. That helps it maintain a larger density. I don't think this would work for a planet that has _less_ mass than Earth. (But figuring out the calculations is beyond me also, I'm just thinking.)